# SHINY Summarise info based on sheet selected by user after uploading file

Tags: r, excel, shiny, shiny-reactivity

My goal is that user uploads an Excel file. Then, the user selects which sheets wants to be summarised, after the selection has been updated. I have managed to update `selectInput` with the name of the sheets but I have not been able to find\understand how to summarise based on what the sheet selected by the user. Thanks for  any help.

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(data.table)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(readxl)

not_sel <- "Not Selected"

# Define UI for application that draws a histogram
ui <- fluidPage('MAIN TITLE',
                theme = shinytheme('flatly'),
  tabsetPanel(
    sidebarLayout(
      sidebarPanel(
        fileInput('files','Import File', accept = c('.csv','.xlsx'),
                  multiple = F),
        actionButton('boton1', 'Load', icon = icon('table')),
        br(),
        selectInput("indices", "Select SHEET:", choices = c(not_sel))
      ),
  mainPanel(
    tabsetPanel(
      tabPanel('Data',
        tableOutput('tabla'),
        tableOutput('cabeza')),
      
      tabPanel('Stats',
        # selectInput('var01', 'Variable to summarise', choices = c(not_sel)),
        tableOutput('stats')),      
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

##############

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  options(shiny.maxRequestSize=10*1024^2) 
  
  df <- eventReactive(input$boton1, {
    req(input$files)
    if(is.null(input$files))return(NULL)
    # else{
    read_excel(input$files$datapath)
    # }
  })
 
  # Sheets of file uploaded
  sheets_name <- reactive({
    if (!is.null(input$files)) {
      return(excel_sheets(path = input$files$datapath))  
    } else {
      return(NULL)
    }
  })

  # Update inputSelector with sheet names
  observeEvent(df(),{
    choices <- c(sheets_name())
    updateSelectInput(inputId = "indices", choices = choices)
  })
  
  
  # DATA Tab
  ## This will show the name of the file

  output$tabla <- renderTable({
    input$files$name
  })
  
  ## This Shows the head() but it is only showing the first sheet

  output$cabeza <- renderTable({
    tabla <- as_tibble(bind_cols(Date = format(as.Date(df()$Date),"%Y-%m-%d"),
                                 Close.Price = df()$Close))
    head(tabla)
  })
  
  # HERE is where I do not know how to calculate based on selection
  # Table for STATS
  output$stats <- renderTable({
    datos <- df()
    Value <- c(round(mean(datos$Close,na.rm = T),2)
               )
    Statistic <- c("Mean")
    data.table(Statistic, Value)
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I want to assume that by knowing how to calculate mean based on the sheet selected, I. can replicate the code for the top rows (`head()`) shown in the *Data* Panel.
If I missed a similar question asked, I would appreciate any link and I will try the solution proposed first.

As I cannot share the file, this is how the file would look:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

After working with [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67264759/r-shiny-openxlsx-uploaded-xlsx-file-select-a-sheet-from-drop-down-menu) answer I made my app work. If there is a 'cleaner'/'better' answer, I will be happy to read.

Following the recommendation in the linked answer my server ended up like this:

```
ui <-fluidPage{
#My UI stayed the same with the exception of adding 
        uiOutput("dropdownUI") #Whererever I needed to appear 
}

server <- function(input, output, session) {
...ANSWER FROM THE LINK...
  ## STATS Tab
  output$stats <- renderTable({
    Values <- c(round(mean(Dat()[,2],na.rm = T),2)
               )
    Statistics <- c("Mean")
    data.table(Statistics, Values)
    })
}
```